# What is the RUST equivalent of following C code?

Tags: c, rust, borrow-checker, stack-memory, stack-pointer

I have a small C code which demonstrate Runtime Stack functionality by modifying data at a stack address.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int * fun() {
    int a = 10;
    return &a;
}
int * fun2() {
    int b = 20;
    return &b;
}

int main () {
    int *a = fun();
    int *b = fun2();
    printf("a:%d b:%d\n", *a, *b);
    return 0;
}
```

Output of this is :
a:20 b:20
which shows 'b' in 'fun2' used the same stack address as 'a' in 'fun'.

i want to test this in Rust too. What would be the simplest way to do this?

I tried Borrowing but compiler says "No value to borrow".

Comment: Isn't this undefined behaviour in C?

Comment: It _is_ undefined behaviour in C.

Comment: I can't find a reference for it, but I would think so it. Even if it is defined behaviour, it's fragile, confusing and pointless. I would be really disappointed if the Rust borrow checker would let you write code that imitates this, without at least using `unsafe`.

Comment: As [many] others have pointed out, returning the address [and trying to use it] of a stack based variable (e.g. `a` and/or `b` in the func) is UB (undefined behavior) because these variables go "out of scope" upon return from the functions. The C code is broken/wrong. So, before trying to convert the code, fix the C code.

Comment: *"which shows 'b' in 'fun2' used the same stack address as 'a' in 'fun'"*, actually not really... It is undefined behavior, so it doesn't really show anything. That's the thing with Undefined Behavior: you can't reason about it at C level, at all. You can of course examine the generated assembly and reason about that, but that's reasoning about assembly, not about C.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to have the same undefined behavior as in C, you can do (luckily, this requires `unsafe`):

```rust
fn fun() -> *const i32 {
    let a = 10;
    &a
}

fn fun2() -> *const i32 {
    let b = 20;
    &b
}

fn main() {
    let a = fun();
    let b = fun2();
    // SAFETY: Don't do this. This is pure Undefined Behavior.
    unsafe {
        println!("a: {} b: {}", *a, *b);
    }
}
```

And this is UB exactly as with the C version. It prints `a: 21885 b: 21885` on the playground on debug mode, and `a: -482758656 b: 32767` on release mode. Yours will be different.

If you also want the same result as the C version, you can use `printf()`. Be careful with the code you use, changes can cause it to no longer "work" as it will use a different stack layout. Of course, this is very fragile:

```
use std::ffi::c_char;

fn fun() -> *const i32 {
    let a = 10;
    &a
}

fn fun2() -> *const i32 {
    let a = 20;
    &a
}

extern "C" {
    fn printf(format: *const c_char, ...);
}

fn main() {
    let a = fun();
    let b = fun2();
    unsafe {
        printf(b"a: %d b: %d\n\0" as *const u8 as *const c_char, *a, *b);
    }
}
```

It prints `a: 20 b: 20` on debug mode, and `a: 1 b: 1` on release (and yours may be different).

Comment: "have the same undefined behavior as in C" maybe is better as "have some undefined behavior as in C".  Doubtful one can specify same-ness of something undefined.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica The same idea.

Comment: fair point.  Just hope readers see any UB in one and any UB in the other are classifiable as the _same_ - both broke.

Comment: Thanks. Second program (with Unsafe/printf) was exactly what i was looking for, and it did give me a:20 b:20. I marked the answer as accepted. First one keeps outputting a: 0 b:0 though.

Answer (score 4):

> What is the RUST equivalent of following C code?

Goal is questionable as C code is bad.

---

`int *a = fun();` is *undefined behavior* (UB) as code attempts to save an invalid pointer.  Copying invalid pointers is UB.  The later attempted reference of `*a` in `printf("a:%d b:%d\n", *a, *b);` is also UB.

```
int * fun() {
    int a = 10;
    return &a; // &a invalid when function completes.
}
```

Comment: intention was to demonstrate/test runtime stack behaviour, so UB was perfectly fine. issue was i was not able to implement it in rust as i am still new to it.

Answer (score 2):

`a` and `b` have automatic storage and are destroyed once the function returns. Once a function returns, it's stack frame is popped (destroyed). Returning the address of (and using) the local variables invokes Undefined Behaviour as per the following clause of the C11 standard:

> 6.2.4 Storage durations of objects:
>
> 2 The lifetime of an object is the portion of program execution during
> which storage is guaranteed to be reserved for it. An object exists,
> has a constant address, and retains its last-stored value throughout
> its lifetime. **If an object is referred to outside of its lifetime, the
> behavior is undefined. The value of a pointer becomes indeterminate
> when the object it points to reaches the end of its lifetime.**

Comment: yes, that's exactly what i was trying to see hands-on . whether the stack frames are destroyed or still kept.

Comment: @oneneozero oneneozero I think you misunderstand UB.  UB is not any sort of defined behavior.  Getting expected data does not mean the frame was not destroyed.  The next time code is run, the results may differ.

Comment: "whether results would differ or not" was exactly what i was checking for. Implementing in rust was the only issue because of borrow checker security. I was not expecting any defined behaviour. I was able to see in C that the behaviour was undefined, but i was not even able to implement the same in rust.

Answer (score 1):

literally the same:

```rust
#![no_main]

extern {
    fn printf(format: *const u8, ...); // u8 or i8 doesn't matter in this case
}

#[no_mangle]
extern fn fun() -> *const i32 {
    let a = 10;
    &a
}

#[no_mangle]
extern fn fun2() -> *const i32 {
    let a = 20;
    &a
}

#[no_mangle]
unsafe extern main() -> i32 {
    let a = fun();
    let b = fun2();
    printf("a:%d b:%d\n\0".as_ptr(), *a, *b);
    0
}
```

Comment: thanks. this keeps printing a: 0 b:0 every time though. (on mac)

Comment: @oneneozerooneneozero, yes! It’s called `undefined behavior`. This happens because local variables are stored on the stack, but after function call the stack is cleaned, so these variables aren’t valid!

Comment: @Milao , thanks but i think printf might be causing the issue. if i replace the printf with "printf(b"a: %d b: %d\n\0" as *const u8 , *a, *b);"  output will be "a: 20 b: 20" always.